# How do data pipelines manager compare to job schedulers?

Tags: apache-spark

Recently the number of available data pipeline engine has growing significantly, with many large players developing their own solution, including Spotify Luigi, Ruigi, Airflow, and many others.

What are the key differences and benefits of deploying a data pipeline manager with respect to simply scheduling jobs, for example, on a Spark Cluster?

Answer (score 1):

While scheduling a few jobs is fairly straightforward, when you have hundreds of inter-dependent jobs and maybe several environments (development, staging, production) it becomes quite unruly.

You want to catch as quickly as possible issues with data, and to do that you want to collect job statistics - how many records were processed, how many were produced, how long it took to run the job. You want to track its history, how long did it take today and how long did it take yesterday ? If today it took 30% longer maybe there is an issue ?

Also, jobs may be dependent on each other, so you want to automate these dependencies, and check that the input data is actually present before starting the job, for instance, that today's data is actually there.

Also, you may have jobs that don't use only one technology - they may do something in HBase, then use spark, load to mysql, then execute a shell script.

So beside scheduling, there's a whole set of functionalities that become really important when prompt delivery of clean, correct data is the bread and butter of your company. In general, many of these functionalities are best practices in a well-run data warehouse. Those practices are antecedent to 'Big Data' but they do still apply, and if you'd like there's an excellent book I can point you to.

Comment: This guy actually wrote several, the one I was referring to is this https://www.amazon.com/Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Definitive-Dimensional/dp/1118530802/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1509560821&sr=1-1&keywords=data+warehouse+kimball but also there's a Data Warehousing collection https://www.amazon.com/Kimballs-Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Classics/dp/1118875184/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1509560821&sr=1-2&keywords=data+warehouse+kimball . They are a great read if you're interested in large scale data warehousing.